# How to catch empty response error in JavaScript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, long-polling

I'm developing chat app using the `long polling` technique for real time updates, but after a few minutes of "polling" a request I get the following error:

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

As I read , this is expected if the requests waits too long then after a while it responses an empty response , Now I would like to be noticed when such a thing happens ,so I can resend another request to the server.

here is my code :

`client.js`:

```
function httpMsgRequest(counter,callback){
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
                    callback(httpRequest.responseText); // we're calling our method
                }
            }
        };
        httpRequest.open('GET', "http://localhost:8080/messages?counter=" + counter);
        httpRequest.send();
}

function msgPoll() {
    try{
        httpMsgRequest(counter,function(res){
            //callback body
            msgPoll();
        });
    }catch{ 
        msgPoll();
    }
}    

msgPoll();
```

I tried to add the `try-catch` like above but it did not solve the problem. Any one has some idea and can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you handle normal server answer ? Once you can answer this question, you'll be able to handle this error.

Comment: @NathanP. thank you for replying ,I tried to add else for the condition of the status=200 , in the else I called the msgPoll() function , it really sends now anew polling request , but the error still appears in the console, how can I prevent it from appearing?

Comment: I think you can't, it comes from the browser.

Comment: @NathanP. you are right , here's what I just did and it works perfectly: http://blog.nemikor.com/2010/05/21/long-polling-in-nodejs/